# I am beginner.. Wants to start working with Flash.. Can someone tell me what is exactly required software to start with?

Tags: flash

I am beginner.. Wants to start working with Flash.. Can someone tell me what is exactly required software to start with? and how to start programming Flash . and What is the major difference between flash and JAVA Applet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start *programming* in ActionScript3 I would recommend you to use an open-source [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/).

Comment: I installed FlashDevelop.. but I am unable to switch to AdobeFlashProfessional.. When I press F6. Its saying The path to Flash.exe(Adobe Flash Professional) is not configured properly, Could you help me on this?

Comment: @user2714918 those are two independent programs. `FlashDevelop` allows you to build programs in AS3 but it doesn't allow you to draw graphics by hand like in `Adobe Flash` (it doesn't have any graphics editor). So in `FlashDevelop` you can use graphics created programmatically or created in some other program like `Adobe Flash`.

Comment: @user2714918 ... that is why the word `programming` is formatted italic in my answer.

Comment: What I can do extra with FlashDevelop when compared to Adobe Flash??

Comment: Does anyone have AdobeFlash serial number?? I have downloaded the 30 day free trail version and my installation stalled as i dont have the serial number

Comment: @user2714918 `FlashDevelop` is open-source and free. That is it's killer-feature compared to `Adobe Flash`.

Comment: SOrry to irritating you.. Please clarify my last doubt... What we can do with Adobe Flash and what not??? and What we can do with FlashDevelop and what not?

Comment: @user2714918 I did not work neither with `FlashDevelop` nor with `Adobe Flash` for a couple of years, so I may be mistaking. I believe that the main difference between them is that `Adobe Flash` has a graphics editor which allows you to draw something by hand (`FlashDevelop` doesn't have a graphics editor). Also `Adobe Flash` has some additional AS3 libraries installed (I'm not sure, but I think they are not open-source and you can not use them in `FlashDevelop`). Both toolkits allow you to write, compile and run AS3 code.

Answer (score 0):

you start with adobe flash cs 6.  With the help of air you can convert flash files to android and iphone/ipad application.  It also support action script 3

thanks

Comment: Is there any difference between adobe flash cs 6 and Adobe flash 12.0?

Comment: @user2714918 Flash CS6 is a flash creation software, Flash Player 12.0 is a runtime of flash.

Answer (score 0):

Flash is a good platform to begin with. You should go with Adobe Flash CS3 or above as it supports action script 3.0. But before this I would like to recommend you to go with HTML 5 or javaScript/jQuery to write software or animation as you do not need any additional plugin or paid software to begin with, one can design a whole software with notepad(expert-level).

You can find the differences [here](http://logicpool.com/archives/30) .